# Google cloud disableing ephemeralIP

Tags: ip, google-cloud-platform, cloud-computing

Is there possibility to turn off globally assigning of ephemeral IPs to instances? I want to have only internal addresses for instances behind nat.

Answer (score 0):

Add `--no-address` argument when creating instances with gcloud command:
https://cloud.google.com/sdk/gcloud/reference/compute/instances/create

> gcloud compute instances create [INSTANCE_NAME] --no-address

Comment: Is it possible to force it for GKE too? I can't find such switch when im starting cluster/node-pool. That's why im asking about "globall" turn off, for one instance i know it is possible. I can't understand why it is not like in AWS with default tuned off external IPs, it is better approach i think.

Comment: Not yet. See this question: [Can GKE cluster nodes be created without external IPs?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42094139/can-gke-cluster-nodes-be-created-without-external-ips)

Answer (score 0):

I find out there is alpha version of gcloud command which can do what i need, with Organization Policies. You can specify which instances should have external IP or with other approach which should not have to.

https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/configure-ip-addresses#disableexternalip